# Postgresql List foreign data wrappers?

Tags: postgresql

[This](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) explains how to create a foreign data wrapper.

So how to list all the existing  foreign data wrappers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many FDWs are listed in the Postgres Wiki:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

`psql` has useful commands as well to know which FDWs are defined, e.g. `\dew[+]`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: This is very useful. Is there a way to list the foreign tables and servers in fdw context.

Comment: @Viraj: presumably. Use `psql -E` and `\dew+` to see the precise queries that target the catalog, and how they're stored in it.

Answer (score 6):

Just `\det`, or `\det[+]` for more details.

[See official documentation here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT fdwname FROM pg_foreign_data_wrapper;`

see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-foreign-data-wrapper.html